# Regex for validating date in dd-Mmm-yyyy format

Tags: regex, validation, date

I have an text input box which needs to be validated. The user should be only able to enter the date in dd-Mmm-yyyy format. ex: 01-Jun-2013, 31-Aug-2015 and so on. Or they should be able to enter T+1, T+2,...T+99.

What kind of a regex pattern I could use to validate both of these. I think for validating the dd-Mmnm-yyyy, the following regex works:

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

Please help me with this!

Update: I just need the regex pattern for a single letter T followed by "+" and a number ranging from "1 to 99". i.e., [T+1... T+99]. The user should be only able to enter these numbers into the text field.

Comment: So are you asking a question or giving an answer with regards to the regex you showed?  Is it not working for you?  Can you give examples of matches that are/aren't being made that are unexpected?

Comment: Try this: http://www.regexr.com/3bdel

Comment: BTW You might be better off using some Date and/or Date validation classes to do this rather than regex, as regex is going to have a hard time picking up problems like leap years or invalid days of month concerns like entering `31-Feb-2015`.

Comment: Yeah, +1 to Mike's point. You should probably be using a library for this. What language is it for?

Comment: Yeah. I ended up using a date-picker :D Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Its for C# :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> T followed by "+" and a number ranging from "1 to 99"

Try with: `T\+?\d{0,2}` where:

1. `T` literal "T";
2. `\+?` - zero or one plus sign "+" with escape backslash (or other escape character, depends on language) - without it it will be treated as metacharacter '+'; the additional '?' sing means, that character before that could appear, but it is not necessary
3. `\d{0,2}` - from zero to two digits;

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO2cR7/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I also need to include T with the above regex. Do I need to  do something like this : ([T]|[T\+\d{0,2}]) . This is working fine. But I don't know if there is any other way. I am learning it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by T+1, etc, but here's the bare minimum that does what you need:

`^[01][0-9]-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$`

You can also use the `i` flag to make the whole thing case insensitive.

http://www.regexr.com/3bdeu

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, I added the possibility to enter someting matching `(T\+[0-9]+)` to your original regex.

```
^((([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4})|(T\+[0-9]+)$
```